# Combining models or entities?

Tags: java, architecture, mvp, n-tier-architecture, clean-architecture

I have one SOLID problem when it comes to separating concerns.
In typical three-tier architecture (model,view,presenter), in which we are approaching the problem following Clean Architecture approach (Uncle Bob), what is the way that models/data are combined? Here is a typical example. The table Pencil doesn't hold information whether it had been shared or not, that information is stored in another table - say, PencilProperties. Then, when I create the Domain Model - PencilModel - what is the proper way to set its "isShared" field that is dependent on this PencilProperties table?

I am using Repository that is just mapping data between PencilDatabaseObject and PencilModel through a data mapper class.

Another example would be, we have two objects:

```
Plant
 -> id
 -> name

Tree
 -> id
 -> plant_id
 -> plant_name
```

at which point I need to map between Plant and Tree, so that the Tree gets the properties from Plant entity?
Accessing the database in the data mapper at this point seems wrong concerning SOLID.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So in both cases, `Pencil`, `PencilProperties`, `Plant` and `Tree` are your data entities.  Your repository should be responsible for fetching data. It should not matter whether your repository is a database, an ORM, or a dictionary). The only thing that matters is the way you want to implement it.

(excuse the C# LINQ, but it's close enough to Java)
So for implementation you could have the repository fetch the isShared simply as:

`var pencilIsShared = _pencilRepository.First().IsShared;`

As for when you need to map it, the simple answer is, "in your repository"

Since your `Pencil` is less likely to change than `PencilRepository`, you'll want to invert the dependency and make sure you have an `PencilRepository` interface, and your `PencilRepositoryImpl` implementation will be the one to return to you whether or not a `Pencil` is shared.

As for your concern about accessing the database in the data mapper, what you can do is include your mapper logic in the repository, and then abstract the mappers so you're no longer violating SRP. See the link below.

*Repository Pattern*

This one is pretty clean: https://medium.com/@krzychukosobudzki/repository-design-pattern-bc490b256006